# laravel: users, authors and posts relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need advise on laravel model relationships, i have a user model, author model, event model,  and post model, the idea is that content authors can create many posts, and can create many events, so i have setup a one-to-one relatinship with user and author, then i setup a one to many with author and posts, author and events. I don't want a user model to have many posts, and events, but i want an author model to be related to the posts, events etc, to  please advise if this is the best way to do it.

User Model:

class User extends Authenticatable
{

```
public function author(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Author');
}
```

}

Author Model:

class Author extends Model
{

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Event');
}
```

}

Post Model:

Class Post extends Model
{

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');
}
```

}

Event Model:

class Event extends Model
{

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I mean, in terms of relationships it's fine if that's what you want to know.

Comment: thanks, well i wanted to know if am following the right approach